# Parse.User.save() doesn't work with Facebook API

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using the Facebook SDK to auth a user, and trying to save the user's email to the record after authenticating. However, I keep getting an error on the save call.

The code in question:

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn({
    access_token: authResponse.access_token,
    expiration_date: expire_date.toISOString(),
    id: response.id
    },
      {
       success: function(user) {
               console.log("success!");
               user.set({"email":response.email});
               user.save();
               window.App.navigate("#myplaces", {trigger:true});
              },
...
```

That user.save() call returns `error occurred: http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.14.min.js:1: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object`.

According to the docs, I have to be in an authentication call (".logIn", etc.) to perform save(), so I'm wondering if this still works with Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn. Seems like it should.

Ideas as to why this isn't working? The ideal behavior is to log the user in, retrieve information from the FB response, and save that back to the user record on Parse.

Thanks!

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but I had the same problem in Cloud Code and I used success/error callbacks when calling save(...):

```
user.save(null, {
  success: function(){
    // Code
  },
  error: function(){
    // Code
  }
});
```

See also here: https://parse.com/questions/saving-a-relation-on-the-current-user